# gstreamer filesrc raw image conversion issue

Tags: gstreamer, mp4

I have captured a raw image which is converted to jpg image using ffmpeg successfully.

Raw image(1920x1080 YUV422).
fmpeg -f rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i raw_data_0 test3.jpg

**Now, I want convert it using gstreamer, My gstreamer version is 1.16.3, below is the pipeline used:
**

```
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location="Testimage.yuv" ! "video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1" ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! "video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream" ! h264parse ! flvmux ! filesink location=test.mp4  > test.log
```

**below is logs:**

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1, format=(string)Y42B
Redistribute latency...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstX264Enc:x264enc0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1, format=(string)Y42B
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0: Internal GStreamer error: code not implemented.  Please file a bug at http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer.
Additional debug info:
gstvideofilter.c(292): gst_video_filter_transform (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0:
invalid video buffer received
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0: Internal GStreamer error: code not implemented.  Please file a bug at http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer.
```

Test image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8gMv.jpg)

****Convert test image to yuv using below command****

```
ffmpeg -i Testimage.jpg -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv422p Testimage.yuv
```

For checking

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv422p -s 1920x1080 -i Testimage.yuv Testimage2.jpg
```

Please suggest what is wrong in gstreamer pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a jpeg image with an h264 encoder. Try jpegenc instead.  something like:

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="Testimage.yuv" ! "video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=1920,height=1080" ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! filesink location=output.jpg`

should work